# Improve sshuttle speed

Tags: 18.04, ssh, internet

I have been using [sshuttle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sshuttle.1.html) for a long time to keep secure connections on open WiFi networks on my Ubuntu 18.04

Most of the time on high speed networks, using sshuttle makes the connection very slow.

Is there anyway to increase the secure connection speed?

Answer (score 5):

Use `--no-latency-control`

Sshuttle manual:

> --no-latency-control
> Sacrifice latency to improve bandwidth benchmarks. ssh uses really big socket buffers, which can overload the connection if you start doing large file transfers, thus making all your other
> sessions inside the same tunnel go slowly. Normally, sshuttle tries to avoid this problem using a "fullness check" that allows only a certain amount of outstanding data to be buffered at a
> time.  But on high-bandwidth links, this can leave a lot of your bandwidth underutilized.  It also makes sshuttle seem slow in bandwidth benchmarks (benchmarks rarely  test  ping  latency,
> which is what sshuttle is trying to control).  This option disables the latency control feature, maximizing bandwidth usage.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Why with `--no-latency-control` the upload will be blocked?
After using this option, download speed will be good but upload has been stopped working.